# Ionic App view changes when phone call is in progress for iOS

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework

We are working on an Ionic application where the app view shifts when a phone call is in progress, anyone got any ideas or could direct me on how to fix this ?

Please see screenshot [phone call is in progress and the app's view changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQWE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITabBar` at the bottom, `UITabBar` doesn't move if call status bar toggled. Also, if your application will require a fullscreen, then app will not be affected of call status bar... ...but it will not show the status bar too) Im not sure if Ionic can provide this, but search for it)